# jqGrid - Changing the Label of a Column

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, revealing-module-pattern

I have all UI related methods in UIManager.js module, i.e. loadGrid, filterGrid, reloadGrid, clearGrid etc. I have a need of changing the Heading of a column in my App. So I wrote a function in UIManager as,

```
var UIManager = (function() {
    "use strict";

    var setGridOptions = function (options) {
        var args = options;

        args.$grid.jqGrid(args.options);
    };

    return {
        setGridOptions:setGridOptions
    };
})();
```

then I called it as,

```
UIManager.setGridOptions({
            $grid: $grid,
            options: ["setLabel", "rn", "Sample Heading"]

        });
```

Please note that following variable was initialized before calling the UIManager.setGridOptions.

```
var $grid = $("#grid"); //Element.
```

Sadly, the UIManager.setGridOptions doesn't work. I am not sure if there is something wrong with passing the options as array or anything else.

But, if I change the UIManager.setGridOptions to the following then it works, but it looses the purpose of having a function.

```
var setGridOptions = function (options) {
    var args = options;
    args.$grid.jqGrid("setLabel", "rn", "Sample Heading");
    //$grid.jqGrid(args.options);        

};
```

Can we fix the code in the call, to use our function? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Come on guys! No reply even after 5 days?